# C# WPF, Window2 Combobox Default Item to Set MainWindow Background, Error on Initialize

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have **MainWindow** and a button that opens **Window2**.

From **Window2** I set the **MainWindow's** background image with a Combobox.

It works perfectly, but If I try to Initialize a Default Combobox Item or Set Default in XAML, I get an error like it can't find the MainWindow.

Exception:Thrown: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

**MainWindow**

```
// Open Configure Window
window2 = new Window2();
window2.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
window2.Show();
```

**Window 2**

```
public Window2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Set Default Combobox Default Item
    if ((string)comboBox1.SelectedItem.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = "Background 1";
    }
}

// Combobox Selection Changed    
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Call MainWindow
        MainWindow mainwindow = this.Owner as MainWindow;

        // Combobox Item Selection
        if ((string)comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Background 1")
        {
            // Background Image
            ImageBrush changeBg = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(BaseUriHelper.GetBaseUri(this), "Resources/bg1.jpg")));

            // Change MainWindow Background
            mainwindow.Background = changeBg;
        }
    }
```

I have also tried this, but it throws another error.

```
MainWindow mainwindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

Exception:Thrown: "Unable to cast object of type 'MyProject.Window2' to type 'MyProject.MainWindow'"

Comment: Why don't you use parameterized constructor of Window2. Pass  a parameter of type MainWindow to Window2 constructor.

Comment: I did this and created constructor in Window2 and it worked, thanks.

MainWindow mainwindow = this;
window2 = new Window2(mainwindow);